# How to set the animation time of a paragraph based on the length of the text in the paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I currently have a marquee style of text scrolling from right to left using pure CSS3 animation.

HTML:

```
<p class="marquee">
    <span>
        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in metus id urna mattis tempor. 
        </a>
    </span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: marquee 45s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  } 100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);    
  }
}
```

Right now, the paragraph is scrolling fine and I am happy with the speed but I want to extend its usability to be able to handle different length of text and have the animation speed dependent on the length of the text.

Ideally, what I want to do is have the animation speed slow enough for the text to be read and when all of the text is shown, the animation will again resume.

CSS alone might not be able to achieve (or can it?) so I am looking for a way to have it implemented through JS or even jQuery. I just do not know how to do this in a practical way, JSwise.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: You seem to think everyone knows what's defined in the `marque` keyframes animation. It's not a standard feature, it's some custom animation someone coded and named `marquee`. It could be anything and, without knowing what it does, we can't really help. Please create a **runnable** [mcve] of your current script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is your actual animation result:

```css
.marquee {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  //position: absolute;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: marquee 45s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  } 100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);    
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
  <span>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in metus id urna mattis tempor. 
    </a>
  </span>
</p>
```

That was to visually notice the animation speed.

Now to *«extend its usability to be able to handle different length of text and have the animation speed dependent on the length of the text.»*...

You will notice that I used the `width` instead of the `.length`. That is because the `.length` returns how many characters there is... And all characters do not occupy the same space.

Now that only is math a rule of three where you define some defaults for a "tested" width and delay (the speed you want):

```js
// Establish the speed you want.
// This is based on what you had on your "test" string prior to any modification using a script.
var defaultDelay = 45; // Is the CSS defined delay.
var defaultWidth = 602; // Is the width for your tested 100 char string.

$(".marquee a").each(function(){

  var width = $(this).width();
  console.log("width: "+width);
  
  var newDelay = defaultDelay*(width/defaultWidth);
  console.log("newDelay: "+newDelay);

  $(this).closest("span").css("animation", "marquee " + newDelay + "s linear infinite");
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*position: absolute;*/    /* Removed */
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: marquee 45s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  } 100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="marquee">
  <span>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in metus id urna mattis tempor. 
    </a>
  </span>
</p>

<p class="marquee">
  <span>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in metus id urna mattis tempor. - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in metus id urna mattis tempor. 
    </a>
  </span>
</p>

<p class="marquee">
  <span>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    </a>
  </span>
</p>
```

The three `.marquee` above are animated to the same "speed".

Answer (score 0):

I attached a jsfiddle below, basically you use jQuery to get the length of the paragraph, you store that value in a variable and you use that variable to set the time, 1 character = 1 second but i think that you can change that, I do not have the full code so it may need a bit of adaptation but I think you can figure out how it works cause it's only 2 lines of jQuery:

```
var length = $(".marquee").text().length;
$(".marquee").css("animation", "marquee" + length + "linear infinite");
```

First line you get the length and store it in a variable, second line you use that length.

Let me know if you need help.

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/552381/